# mysql - select hour in datetime and group

Tags: mysql

I have a datetime column of ShoppingDates.

Lets say I have 1000 rows of

7/18/2012 5:33:39 PM

7/16/2012 6:64:39 PM

7/14/2012 7:34:39 PM

7/13/2012 8:30:39 PM

7/13/2012 8:37:39 PM

ect....

I want to count the number of times that each time appears within an hour time frame

```
so 5:00 p.m - 5:59:59 pm
so 6:00 p.m - 6:59:59 pm
so 7:00 p.m - 7:59:59 pm
so 8:00 p.m - 8:59:59 pm
```

so in the above result I would get

```
1|5pm-6pm
1|6pm-7pm
1|7pm-8pm
2|8pm-9pm
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 68):

I suspect you just want something like:

```
SELECT HOUR(ShoppingDate), COUNT(*) FROM YourTable
GROUP BY HOUR(ShoppingDate)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT( HOUR(ShoppingDate), ' to ', CONCAT( HOUR(ShoppingDate), ':59:59' ) ) as time_frame,
  COUNT(*) 
FROM 
  temp
GROUP BY 
  DATE(ShoppingDate), 
  HOUR(ShoppingDate)
```

Here's the [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/98e38/1)

**Note:** I assume ShoppingDate is a datetime field